# Spring security 3.2 - @PostAuthorize expressions to evaluate principal against the method's returned object

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-el, spring-4

I use spring security to secure and evaluate expression in @PostAuthorize and @PreAuthorize annotations to authorize the service methods. I have a requirement that need to check if the returned object has the same userid who has logged in the system and is invoking this method.

```
// this allows the ids of other users too
@PostAuthorize("#returnObject!=null?returnObject.userId==principal.account.acid:true")
public AudioClip findAudioClip(int clipId) {
     .....
     AudioClip clip = dao.findById(clipId);
     // may also be null
     return clip;
}
```

AudioClip.java

```
@Component
public class AudioClip implements java.io.Serializable {

private java.math.BigDecimal id;
private java.lang.Integer    userId;
.....
}
```

The fetched object from the database contains the userId who created this db object. So, only he is eligible to access that component. How to compare the returnObject.userId with the userid who has logged-in to the system?

Comment: ya, I will correct it

Comment: Just to be sure, your PostAuthorize annotation, while looking fine does not bloc anything, right ? If it true, could you try to add a `@PreAuthorize("denyAll")` and if it correctly blocs `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_CAESAR_IMPERATOR')")` (assuming you do not have such a role) and say what happens ?

Comment: Having edited the original question to have the correct answer posted is confusing.  You got rid of the # which was the problem and why it was posted in the first place.  Took me a while to figure out what the difference in the problem and the solution were because of that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@holmis, as you had pointed, the culprit is the # in the code! this code

```
@PostAuthorize("returnObject!=null?returnObject.userId==principal.account.aid:true")
```

works!

Comment: I would also recommend instead of doing the null check inside the @ PostAuthorize to do it in the method and throw some kind of NOT FOUND error there, this way you skip the @ PostAuthorize check for empty objects

Answer (score 1):

same thing but i find this reads better than the answer by @vijay.

```
@PostAuthorize("returnObject == null ?: returnObject.userId == principal.account.aid")
```

see [6.5.14 The Elvis Operator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html)